# Read delimited record containing delimited field with varying length with FileHelpers in C#?

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I am using MultiRecordEngine() to read a delimited .txt file with no header and different type of records. The first two character of any record is the identifier which I am using to identify the type of the record.

The problem I am encountering is that in RecordB(see sample model below), I have a field which contains multiple values delimited with the same delimiter being used in the file. And also the field length is not fixed, it's length depends on the number of values in it. for e.g. `FieldB-0000-1111-2222-3333-FieldD` where `0000-1111-2222-3333` will need to be read in `FieldC`.

*Note: `FieldB` contains an integer which denoted the amount of values that will be present in `FieldC`*

I am using MultiRecordEngine() to read the file and map the records to my models for the different type of records.

A sample that looks close to what I have:

1 sample model

```
[DelimitedRecord("-")]
public class RecordB
{
    public string RecordIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string FieldA { get; set; }
    public string FieldB { get; set; } <-- contains a value determining the amount of values in FieldC
    public string FieldC { get; set; } <-- read delimited values to this field [delimiter: -]
    public string FieldD { get; set; }
    public string FieldE { get; set; }
}
```

Reading the file using MultiRecordEngine

```
new MultiRecordEngine(RecordSelector,
    typeof(RecordA),
    typeof(RecordB),
    typeof(RecordC),
);
```

My RecordSelector looks similar to:

```
switch (recordType)
{
    case "XX":
        return typeof(RecordA);
    case "XY":
        return typeof(RecordB);
    default:
        return null;
}
```

I did try using a combination of `[DelimitedRecord("-")]` and `[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.AllowLessChars)]` on the model as well as `[FieldDelimiter("~")]` on the field but no luck. Is there anything I'm missing? Please advise.

Comment: if you could write small unit test the way your input given and the way you expect output really helps, rather going through your all complex logic,

Comment: I can put as simple as, I want to read a delimited record which contains a field with delimited value and the field length is not fixed. How do I achieve that with filehelper?

Comment: as clear as mud, so to understand better `FieldB-0000-1111-2222-3333-FieldD where 0000-1111-2222-3333 is FieldC value` here FieldA is missing is that correct? also can any row can have  more than one fieldB ex, FieldA and Field  since length is not fixed.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. Yes, ```FieldA``` is missing, it is the record identifier (e.g. ```XY```). 
I'm not sure I understood your second question correctly. What I can tell, no, only one FieldB per record with identifier ```XY```. The other fields length are not fixed as well but I am able to get the values by splitting on the delimiter.
The only issue I am facing is to get the delimited values for ```FieldC```.

Comment: I think I'm leaning towards reading from ```FieldC``` to the end of the record in a property and then split the values by the count in ```FieldB``` respectively. Yet to figure out how to do this.
FileHelper does not allow this on delimited field I guess.

Comment: @coder_b Please see answer below. I appreciate your time for looking into the issue. Thanks!

Comment: the easiest option I could think off replace "FieldA","FieldB","FieldC"  with "" empty string that means what is left is  FieldD property value, then the same applies to other fields for example "FieldA","FieldB","FieldD" with empty string that means the remaining text would be value of "FieldC".. so on.

Comment: ok but how would I know that I have reached "FieldD" to replace its value when I do not know the length of "FieldC"? keeping in mind that these values are being mapped onto the model properties dynamically via MultiRecordEngine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. I'm using the model below to read only the record I know that contains the delimited field and splitting the values later and getting them by index.

```
[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.ExactLength)]
public class RecordB
{
    [FieldFixedLength(100)]
    public string WholeRecord { get; set; }
}
```